# How to get Post ID in bootstrap Modal in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Please help me to get the ID from specific products. When I click on the product, the content of a modal that subsequently opens should also change dynamically to that product. So far I already have the modal functioning, but my problem is I cannot get the exact ID of every product. Do you have any idea on how can I can get the product ID inside the modal in WordPress?

```html
<a onclick="modal(this);" id="<?php get_the_id();?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Button
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   </div>  
  <div class="col-sm-6">
         </div>
</div>
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: where are the product ids?

Comment: Product Ids are get_the_id(); in wordpress

Comment: you get the id by using `this.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is a property of the event object so you simply do the following:

```js
function modal(e) {
console.log(e.id);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="modal(this);" id="<?php get_the_id();?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Button
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   </div>  
  <div class="col-sm-6">
         </div>
</div>
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: how can get ID from javascript to PHP in modal? @madalin

Comment: yup whenever I do that , it is always same ID that i've got. Whenever I click the product the ID should also change. that's a problem in modal

Comment: then you have a problem with your wp loop, it doesn't set the ids to each product

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code will help you

```
<?php

    $args['post_type']='product';
    $products_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $products_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $products_query->have_posts() ) : $products_query->the_post();
    ?>

    <a onclick="modal(this);" id="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Button</a>
    <?php

    endwhile; endif;

    ?>
```